# GDAL NoDataFill returns as int and won't write to copied raster

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I'm struggling to understand what's going wrong here. I'm just really simply trying to use gdal's nofilldata method to fill the gaps in a raster file. Here's the code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

filename = "in_raster.TIF"
dataset = gdal.Open(filename)

# Check if really dataset
print('datatype is ', type(dataset))

# Get rasterband
rasterband = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

# Fill nodata in raster
ndfill = gdal.FillNodata(targetBand = rasterband, maskBand = None, maxSearchDist = 100, smoothingIterations = 0)

# Create a new copy of the input dataset with the filled data
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
output_ds = driver.CreateCopy("out_raster.tif", dataset)

# Get the first band of the output dataset and write the filled data to it
output_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(ndfill)

# Cleanup 
dataset = None
rasterband = None
output_band = None
output_ds = None
```

This gives me the error: "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'"
Which is understandable since the gdal.nofilldata output is an int object. I've tried shaping it to an array with numpy but that doesn't help either.

Comment: Can you share your input file?

Comment: @BertCoerver, sure: https://we.tl/t-uuXRhMoYaV

Comment: Have you compared your own code with the GDAL Python utility https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal_fillnodata.py?

Comment: @user30184, Yes and I don't think gdal.fillnodata  is the issue here. I don't get how I write the filled results to the copied raster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were a couple of problems.

First of all, it's always usefull to run `gdal.UseExceptions()` at the start of your script. Then you would have gotten a error message on the line where you run `gdal.FillNodata`.

Then, the value returned by `gdal.FillNodata` has nothing to do with the data itself, it's just a "status code", 0 meaning "no problems" and anything else "there was a problem".

Finally, `gdal.FillNodata` actually fills the data "in place", i.e. it adjust the actual band you pass to it. If you want to create a new file with the filled values, you therefor have to create the copy BEFORE you pass it to `gdal.FillNodata`.

Your script wasn't working because the dataset/band you were passing was opened in read-only mode and so couldn't be modified.

So this works:

```
from osgeo import gdal

# Make sure gdal prints errors.
gdal.UseExceptions()

# Define the paths.
input_fh = r"/Users/hmcoerver/Desktop/M_21GZ2_orig.TIF"
output_fh = r"/Users/hmcoerver/Desktop/out.TIF"

# Open the dataset.
ds = gdal.Open(input_fh)

# Check if dataset was opened correctly.
assert isinstance(ds, gdal.Dataset)

# Create a new copy of the input dataset WITHOUT the filled data.
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
output_ds = driver.CreateCopy(output_fh, ds)

# Get the band.
band = output_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# Fill nodata in the band.
_ = gdal.FillNodata(targetBand = band, maskBand = None, maxSearchDist = 100, smoothingIterations = 0)

# Release the datasets.
ds = ds.FlushCache()
output_ds = output_ds.FlushCache()
```

To adjust the original file instead of creating a copy, you could open it like this:

```
from osgeo.gdalconst import GA_Update

ds = gdal.Open(input_fh, GA_Update)
```

Comment: That works! Thank you so much, I wouldn't have figured that one out. Do you have any recommendations for information on gdal?

Comment: If you can, I would recommend you to use higher level libraries built on top of GDAL such as rasterio. They are way more pythonic and way easier to use.

Comment: Yeah, agree with @remi.braun. Better try to use libraries such as rasterio/xarray/rioxarray, although I don't think this particular algorithm is available there. Documentation for the python bindings of gdal are not very good in my opinion. Setting `gdal.UseExceptions()` usually points me in the right direction. (I don't really get why thats not turned on by default...)